# LLVM. AddressSanitizer.Is a value operand of store Instruction function parameter

Tags: llvm

In a file `AddressSanitizer.cpp` there is a function `AddressSanitizer::instrumentStoreInstruction(...)`

```
void AddressSanitizer::instrumentStoreInstruction(StoreInst *S, Instruction *I) {
    assert(nullptr != S);
    assert(nullptr != I);
    Value* V = S->getValueOperand();
    assert(nullptr != V);
    Value* P = S->getPointerOperand();
    assert(nullptr != P);
    DEBUG(dbgs() << "ASAN Store Value : " << " " <<*V << "\n");
    DEBUG(dbgs() << "ASAN Store Pointer" << " " <<*P << "\n");
    Value* vL = 0;
    if (isa<Instruction>(V)) {
        vL = getStoreInstructionValueShadowBit(V, I);
        handleStorePointerOperand(P, I, vL);
    } else if (isa<ConstantExpr>(V)) {
        instrumentConstantExprStoreInstruction(V, P, I);
    } else if (isa<ConstantInt>(V) || isa<ConstantFP>(V)) {
        //TODO: need to change to ConstantData after LLVM porting
        instrumentConstantIntStoreInstruction(V, P, I);
    }
}
```

How to check is store Instruction value operand is a function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isa<Argument>(V)` to check if a value V is a function argument. Documentation for the Argument class can be found here: http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Argument.html.